# Android Studio - Difference between Import project and Open project

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-ide

I have been using Android Studio since one of the first releases (about one year ago, since I/O 2013)

However I have recently noticed that in the first screen when lets you to create a project there are also Open and Import project options, and I cant find any difference between them

I remember that in Eclipse, import project would make a copy of the project in the workspace... However, in Android Studio there is no workspace as far as I know...

So, what are the differences between Import project and Open project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no much difference if you are working with gradle project. Since Android Studio tries to sync project every time when project is opened.

However there is difference if you try to import Eclipse project folder. In this case it will migrate it to gradle project structure.

Watch this new IO video talk to get more about tools https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hu4U8XKmJGA